# Migration of Slack app which uses event api (HTTP end-point) to Slack Socket Mode

Tags: php, websocket, bots, slack-api, slack-commands

I have implemented a Slack app using PHP(HTTP-endpoint). Under slack slash commands, I have inserted the request URL (HTTP end-point which points to the code I have written in PHP to open a Slack Modal ) that opens a dialogue box (Slack Modal). And upon submitting the form it will go to GitHub, that I have inserted the URL of my code written in PHP under request URL in interactivity and shortcuts(Payload).

But due to security measures, I want to migrate the app to socket mode. Can someone please let me know how to implement the socket mode for PHP in my local VM?

This is code to open a dialog box in slack

```
<?php

$slack_token = 'xoxb-******************';

// Dialog Form:
$dialog = [
  'callback_id' => 'git_issue',
  'title' => 'Add issue',
  'submit_label' => 'Create',
  'elements' => [
    [
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => 'Name',
      'name' => 'name'
    ],
    [
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => 'E-mail',
      'name' => 'email'
    ],
    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

// set the POST query parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));

// execute curl request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

How to migrate the application to socket mode?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I use this own-written code. May be it is not perfect, but it works:

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
    // Slack config:
    $slack_token = 'xapp-*';
    $bot_token = 'xoxb-*';
    
    $url = false;
    
    $dialog = [
      'callback_id' => 'git_issue',
      'title' => 'Add new GitHub Issue',
      'submit_label' => 'Create',
      'elements' => [
        [
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => 'Developer\'s Name',
          'name' => 'name'
        ],
      ]
    ];
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://slack.com/api/apps.connections.open');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization: Bearer '.$slack_token
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    
    // set the POST query parameters
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    
    // execute curl request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    // close
    curl_close($ch);
    
    if ($response) {
        $resp = json_decode($response);
        if (isset($resp->url)) {
            $url = $resp->url;
        }
    }
    
    if ($url) {
        echo 'Slack returned the websocket URL'.PHP_EOL;
        $client = new WebSocket\Client($url, ['timeout' => 3600]);
        while (true) {
            try {
                $message = $client->receive();
                
                echo $message.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
    
                if ($message) {
                    $data = json_decode($message);
                    if (isset($data->payload)) {
                        if (isset($data->payload->command) && $data->payload->command == '/git') {
                            // Open Dialog:
    
                            // define POST query parameters
                            $query = [
                                'token' => $bot_token,
                                'dialog' => json_encode($dialog),
                                'trigger_id' => $data->payload->trigger_id,
                            ];
    
                            // define the curl request
                            $ch = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open');
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                            ]);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    
                            // set the POST query parameters
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));
    
                            // execute curl request
                            $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
                            // close
                            curl_close($ch);
                            
                            $query = [
                                'envelope_id' => $data->envelope_id
                            ];
                            $client->text(json_encode($query));
                            // -----------
                        }
    
                        if (isset($data->payload->type) && $data->payload->type == 'dialog_submission') {
                            
                            // collect submitted data:
                            $name = $data->payload->submission->name;
                            
    
                            $query = [
                                'envelope_id' => $data->envelope_id,
                            ];
                            $client->text(json_encode($query));
                        }
                    }
                }
               
            } catch (\WebSocket\ConnectionException $e) {
                // Possibly log errors
                var_dump($e);
            }
        }
        $client->close();
    }
```

**Configure your Slack app and create tokens:**

- go to https://api.slack.com/apps page and select existed one or
  create a new app
- go to "basic information" page, find "App-Level
  Tokens" section. Create a new token. I use these scopes
  "connections:write, authorizations:read" for it
- go to "OAuth & Permissions" page and generate "Bot User OAuth Token"
- go to "slash commands" page and create a command. In my code example we have it with the name "/git"
- go to "Socket Mode" page and enable the mode with a slide button

For **websockets connection via PHP** I use this [Textalk/websocket-php](https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php) realization from GitHub.